# How to raise gold production?

Tags: kingdoms-of-camelot

How to raise gold production in Kingdom of Camelot on Android? I know raising taxes helps but people's are less happy. Any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do any of the following:

- Conquering barbarian camps or other players
- Taxing your population (increase your population through cottages)
- Completing quests
- Selling excess supplies on the market
- Merlin's Gift (by chance)

**Note:** If you are worried about your population's happiness you can raise your taxes to make gold while your not playing, then decrease the taxes when you require the use of your population.

Answer (score 1):

Maximum taxes occurs at 50% tax rate. Because the population available to make money goes down as you raise taxes, each percent you raise the tax you get just a little less than the last percent you raised it by. When you hit 50%, you actually start making less money as you raise the taxes.

A tax rate of 40% gives you `.4 * .6` revenue. But a 60% tax rate gives you `.6 % .4`! So a 40% tax and a 60% tax give the same revenue (once the population balances out after a few hours, of course. It's not instantaneous.)

This is illustrated by the following graph

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that hiring facebook friends gives them an income, which takes away from your gold production.
As they increase in level, their income increases as well. This was a big problem for me at one point. You can fire them or whatever to get rid of their income.

Comment: There are no taverns in the mobile version.

Comment: Oh I didn't see that he said "on Android". Mah Bad. I will fix it. Thanks!